# Why Watson DB records do not get any updates from the mobile App?

Tags: android, ibm-watson

I'm trying to update a field on the Watson DB but I'm not able to, I do not get any error. I think that I properly setted up since I got several records with value on the field *Mobile User Id* and I got all the Push notifications I sent.

So far, I'm using the following lines to try to update the fields, where **myField** is the exact name on the Watson DB.

```
StringAttribute attribute = new StringAttribute("myField", "New Value");
List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<(1);
attributes.add(attribute);

MceSdk.getQueuedAttributesClient().updateUserAttributes(getApplicationContext(), attributes);
```

Should this be enough to perform the update or should I add something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I setup again the service following all the process step by step of the following URL:

https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/tutorials/configuring-basic-push-services-for-android-apps/

And was able to perform updates to the DB using the code from the following URL:

https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/docs/watson-marketing/ibm-engage-2/mobile-push/mobile-push-android/advanced-push-attributes-for-android/

I changed the device too, and I started to get updates on the BD.